# django expected an indented block

Tags: django

I am getting error in line 71

```
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser):
name            = models.CharField(max_length=25)
email           = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
is_active       = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_admin        = models.BooleanField(default=False)

objects = MyUserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

def get_full_name(self):
    # The user is identified by their email address
    return self.email //line error

def get_short_name(self):
    # The user is identified by their email address
    return self.email

def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
    return self.email

@property
def is_staff(self):
    "Is the user a member of staff?"
    # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
    return self.is_admin
```

This is error expected an indented block in "return"

```
 return self.email
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: We have no idea which one of those is line 71. Please provide the entire traceback of the error. Also, please fix your indentation in your question...

Comment: Did you check if you didn't mix tab and space ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole class definition must be indented, like this:

```
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    email           = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
    is_active       = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin        = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email //line error

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.email

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```